# Codeigniter unable to fetch Thai data

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a website which supports Thai language. Now i have the Thai data in my database which is proper, but when am trying to fetch the data and display in my view, some junk content is being displayed like this À¹À¸ŸÀ¸¥À¸ŠÀ¹„À¸”À¸£À¹ŒÀ¸Ÿ À¸„À¸´À¸‡À¸ªÀ¹ŒÀ¸•À¸±À¹‰À¸
   The content is displayed properly when i write a core PHP script and echo it.

```
In my db i have used collation : utf8_general_ci

In codeigniter's  application/config/database.php i have the following configuration.

$db['livedb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['livedb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

And in the header view am using <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Please help me where am i going wrong. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: have you check your codeigniter config.php: set $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

Comment: Yes i have checked in my config.php i tried using  $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; as well as  $config['charset'] = 'utf-8'; none of them worked.

Comment: maybe you find some more info here: http://codeigniter.in.th/

Answer (score 0):

You should use utf-8 meta in your view

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the meta tag for displaying UTF8 in your **head** tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Yes i have added meta tag for displaying UTF8 in my head tag.

And that is what i meant by saying 'And in the header view am using <meta charset="utf-8" />' in the last line of my question.